# C# XML parsing thru EPPlus

Tags: c#, xml

I am parsing XML, I have generated Class from XSD file, I am able to access simple values from XML, but I don't know how to get value from this. I need it as String.

```
public partial class AccountIdentification4Choice {

private object itemField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("IBAN", typeof(string))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Othr", typeof(GenericAccountIdentification1))]
public object Item {
    get {
        return this.itemField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemField = value;
    }
}
```

}

```
In XML value can be like this:
<CdtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>BBAN</Id></Othr></Id></CdtrAcct> 
or
<CdtrAcct><Id><IBAN>BBAN</IBAN></Id></CdtrAcct>
```

## Update - all resource files:

XML: [Priklad_multi.XML](http://matrasovi.cz/Priklad_multi.XML)
XSD: [camt.053.001.02.xsd](http://matrasovi.cz/camt.053.001.02.xsd)

Then I parse XML with EPPlus package:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
 Document resp = ser.Deserialize(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)) as Document;
```

And then I can access XML values like this (for example Stmt-Acct)

```
resp.BkToCstmrStmt.Stmt[ind].Acct.Id.Item
```

But I don't know how to access this CdtrAcct section in same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but as I understand you want to get IBAN tag, right? If so, you could do that easily with Linq To XML. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    string xml1 = "<CdtrAcct><Id><Othr><Id>BBAN</Id></Othr></Id></CdtrAcct>";
    string xml2 = "<CdtrAcct><Id><IBAN>BBAN</IBAN></Id></CdtrAcct>";

    Console.WriteLine(CheckIban(xml1));
    Console.WriteLine(CheckIban(xml2));
}

private string CheckIban(string xml)
{
    var iban = XElement.Parse(xml).DescendantsAndSelf("IBAN").FirstOrDefault();
    if (iban != null)
    {
        return (string)iban;
    }
    iban = XElement.Parse(xml).DescendantsAndSelf("Othr")
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (iban != null)
    {
        return iban.Element("Id").Value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @PavelMatras, still what I understand is the same. You can access it with Linq to XML as I showed above.